# Python: TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, google-translate, translate

I am trying to translate text from Urdu to English using googletrans. I am getting this error message TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable when I try to create a dictionary to translate the elements in the column cells. How do I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

```
    translations = {}
    for column in df_en.columns:
    # unique elements of the column
    unique_elements = df_en[column].unique()
    for element in unique_elements:
    # add translation to the dictionary
    translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text
    
    # modify all the terms of the data frame by using the previously created dictionary
    df_en.replace(translations, inplace = True)

    print(translations)
```

Comment: Can you check your code intendation?

Comment: try to print `unique_elements `

Comment: which line raises the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have previously encountered the same issue. This bug has to deal with your `for` statements. You might want to try changing your code to:

```
for column in range(unique_elements):
    #add translation to the dictionary
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Neha is trying to run the function "unique_element" times, but in Python, the argument you pass in a "for loop" has to be an iterable object, so I changed it to "range(unique_elements)".